# Run function to populate dropdown list in Form on change in sheet cell range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

I am looking for a script to run as soon as a range of cells (example: C2:C) change.
When the script runs I want it to call a Form and update the Form drop-down list with the new values in the cell range C2:C.

I have tried this with an installable trigger, however the trigger fires even when other tabs in the spreadsheet are changed, i.e sheet 2 etc.

```
function updatetestForm(){
// call your form and connect to the drop-down item
var form = FormApp.openById("formID");
var namesList = form.getItemById("12345678").asListItem();

// identify the sheet where the data resides needed to populate the drop-down
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetID");
var names = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");

// grab the values in the first column of the sheet - use 2 to skip the first 1 row (limit of 1000) 
var namesValues = names.getRange(2, 1, names.getLastRow() - 0).getValues();
var test = [];

// convert the array ignoring empty cells
for(var i = 0; i < namesValues.length; i++)    
if(namesValues[i][0] != "")
test[i] = namesValues[i][0];

// populate the drop-down with the array data
namesList.setChoiceValues(test);

}
```

I tried using an installable trigger but the trigger fired when other sheet tabs changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the event that launched the trigger. For example, by changing the title to add the `e` to grab the event, you can check the sheet involved. You can add this first line and wrap the rest of the function with that opening curly bracket (close at the end, obviously)

```
`function updatetestForm(e){

  if(e.range.getSheet().getName() == "sheet1") {
```

You can add more conditions to check the column inside the if statement:

```
if(e.range.getSheet().getName() == "sheet1" && e.range.getColumn() == 3) {
```

And so on

Comment: I get TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range'). Have you tried it to see if it works?

Comment: Have you run it from the console? Functions run with events from edits, don't work from the console since it's meant to trigger when there's a change. Save it and try it by making changes in your spreadsheet

Comment: Initially yes, but nothing happened so I tried running it from the console as a check. I am making a change to the specific sheet/tab. Remember, I am not using an installable trigger at all. Should I be using a trigger on change? Perhaps I have made a mistake in the script, would be good it someone could provide me with the full script.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry; make it as an installable trigger; then it should check if the event is fired from that sheet and column and continue with the execution or not

Comment: one more question. Is it best to run the script in the Sheet or in the Form?

Comment: I'd guess that from the Sheet if that's what's being edited